# Jquery Unable to make Ajax Request to Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I am trying to make an AJAX Request through JQuery 
The below is my code .

But when i debugged through Mozilla Firebug i observed that ,there is no Request hitting to the Server .

Could anybody please tell me where i am doing wrong .

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>



<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JQuery Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                         $.ajax({
                      url: 'ajax/balances',
                      processData: false,
                      timeout: 10000,
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/xml",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: '<MyReq  user="' + User + '" katha="' + ivalitiKatha + '" />',
                     success: function(data) {

                     },
                     error : function() {
                             alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
                     }
             });

                });

        </script>
            </body>
</html>
```

**This is my web.xml on server side**

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/ajax/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: $.ajax Code works for me! a request is send when i use your code on a page where Jquery is present! You could try it here by copying the code to the console of firebug and execute it. Your $.ajax code isn't the problem

Comment: Where are `User` and `ivalitiKatha`? Maybe because of those not defined variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe adding `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the head instead of the body helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend moving the CDN JQuery into the head section of the website.

Secondly I have tested the code above and the issue looks to lie with the (data) you are posting in the JSON / AJAX request.

If you remove it or amend to JSON the request returns a result e.g.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    processData: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{"foo": "bar"}',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Success');                
    },
    error : function() {
        alert("Sorry, The requested property could not be found.");
    }
});​
```

You will need to format the data as a JSON request

```
data: '{"foo": "bar"}',
```

Hope this helps